# installing 'xiaomi notes.apk' through adb on chromebook getting error

Tags: shared-libraries, adb, google-chrome-os, xiaomi, androidappsonchromeos

I have been trying to install xiaomi notes.apk on to my Chromebook through adb but keeps getting this error-

adb: failed to install notes.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Reconciliation failed...: Reconcile failed: Package com.miui.notes requires unavailable shared library micloud-sdk; failing!]

tried installing xiaomi cloud first as well but still getting the same error even in that as well.

so can anyone help me how to install or solve this error-?

Comment: The app is not asking for the "xiaomi cloud" app, but for the `micloud-sdk` system library. Such a library is only present on xiaomi ROMs, thus on xiaomi devices.